# Mysql finding intersecting lat lng point in polygon

Tags: mysql, database

I am looking for a solution for finding wether a LAT,LNG Point is contained inside any Polygon in my MySQL table.

For some reason that extends past my SQL knowledge, my queries using `ST_Intersects` returning 'Function not found'. So i have stried in it's place:

```
SELECT `area_title` FROM `service_areas` WHERE MBRIntersects(`area_poly`, GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(40.775032, -73.970778)'));
```

My table for testing is fairly simply and stores a 
1.     `area_poly GEOMETRY` stores `POLYGON((-71.740723 41.360319,-71.685791 42.106374,-71.71875 42.407235,-71.905518 42.771211,-72.070312 43.036776,-72.432861 43.157109,-72.718506 43.397065,-73.190918 43.55651,-73.619385 43.580391,-74.32251 43.572432,-75.201416 43.277205,-75.717773 43.004647,-75.926514 42.795401,-76.135254 42.528796,-76.256103 42.138968,-76.289062 41.869561,-76.234131 41.442726,-76.190185 40.955011,-75.992432 40.472024,-75.849609 40.153687,-75.629883 39.783213,-75.311279 39.529467,-74.94873 39.368279,-74.520264 39.257778,-74.256592 39.478606,-71.5979 40.971604,-71.740723 41.360319))`
And 
2. `area_title VARCHAR(20)` stores `service area 1`

I am trying to pass a Point as `POINT(40.775032, -73.970778)` as shown above.

Expected result would be to return any `area_title`'s that the point is within it's polygon; However, my query returns `0 Rows`.

I know there are a ton of questions/answers on slack and the web, but i have not found a solution trying most of the methods. With my lack of SQL knowledge i'm not sure if i'm storing the Poly correctly or not using the correct function to find it.

Any help, even pointing in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution for anyone who is running into the same issue:

```
SELECT ea.name, ea.area_poly from service_areas as ea WHERE contains(ea.area_poly, GeomFromText(AsText(point(@lat, @lng)), 4326))
```

My polygon `ea.area_poly` is saved as `Polygon((lat1 lng1,lat2 lng2, etc..))` as a `geometry` type in SQL.